# How to create xml using JAXB with namespace

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to create XML from java objects, it is actually `List<MyElem>`. The MyElem object itself is marshalling ok, though I can't marshal a List of those objects - one of the solutions that comes to mind is creating another class to wrap that list but it seems so be ugly. Is there more elegant way?

And another question - is there a way to provide schema prefix for every element, like
`<n:elem>some val</n:elem>` without specifying it on each property?

*UPD*: in the second question I meant that if I have property like `public String element` it gets marshalled as `<elem>some val</elem>` while I want it (and every other property) be prefixed with `n:`, e.g. `<n:elem>`.

And let me provide code for the first one:

            `List<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Book.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            list.add(new Book());
            list.add(new Book());
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(list, writer);`

which produces

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`

while I want to have book elements inside

Comment: The second question is not clear on what do you mean property ? rephrase it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify as `java.util.List` like below.

```
   @XmlElement(name="myElem")
    List<MyElem> flexField;

    public List<MyElem> getMyElem() {
        if(myElem == null) {
            myElem = new ArrayList<MyElem>();
        }
        return this.myElem;
    }
```